# Releasing iPhone app in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am lost. I am trying to release my first iPhone app, and the instructions in the provisioning portal are leading me into dead ends. Can someone tell me how to do this in XCode 4?

EDIT: Okay, I made the distribution provisioning profile, downloaded it, put it in xcode, and set the release code signing info to it. It archives with no errors. But when I press validate it says "No suitable application records were found."

Comment: You need to ask more specific questions. There is plenty of documentation on Apple's site and others describing how to release.

Comment: Please describe the dead end and how you got there.

Comment: Can u check share instead validate?

Comment: Have you created an app in iTunes Connect yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Ad-Hoc distribution provisioning profile first on your phone then use same configuration for App store distribution provisioning profile. If your Ad-Hoc works then App store distribution provisioning profile has to work.

Comment: Check your App ID and Bundle ID. Are they same ?

Comment: Yes, but the app id has a lot of random digets before it.

Comment: That is fine. Does your developer provisioning profile works on your phone ?

Comment: One more thing you have to change distribution provisioning profile setting four places in your xcode setting. Are you doing that ?

Comment: Oh, I think I'm only doing 2. In both the project and target I change "Release" and "Any iOS SDK" inside it. Am I missing something there?

Comment: In project under "Code signing Identity” -> Debug -> Any iOS SDk, "Code signing Identity” -> Release -> Any iOS SDk, Same for target. Do this hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I thought you only had to setup the app in the provisioning portal, I had no idea there is a different webpage that you put all of the app info into.

The page is: itunesconnect.apple.com

Comment: This is the next thing i was going to check after all the setting i told you to check. But you solve it on your own its good. Please close this question by checking the answer sign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match your App Identifier with the one set in the App distribution profile:

For instance:

```
com.yourSoftwareCompany.yourApp
```

If this don't match your App will not pass the signing verification